# I am facing Issue in size of file Validation in magento 1

Tags: javascript, validation, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have an issue in validating a file in magento form validator,

i have custom validation code for file size like this.

```
 Validation.add('validate-filesize', 'Upload file should be less than 2MB',function(v,elem) {
```

`var file = elem.files;

    var fileSize = file[0].size;

    if(fileSize <= 2000000){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});`

and in my form there are two file filds.

above validation code is working fine for this field.

`<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-filesize">`

but it is failing to validate below field

`<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" value="" class="input-text validate-filesize">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't lie in the library, but in your validator callback function.

You are checking the size of the file using the following code

```
var fileSize = file[0].size
```

But when the user doesn't upload any files, the variable `file[0]` is `undefined`. Thus when you do `file[0].size`, it throws an error saying `Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`. And that's why further processing of your code stops and you don't get the desired message.

A good way of doing it would be to check if the user has uploaded any files before checking it's size, like so.

```
var file = elem.files;

if(file.length == 0) return true; // all is good if user didn't upload any file

//go ahead with the rest of the code otherwise

var fileSize = file[0].size;

if(fileSize <= 2000000){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```